# Screenshot a separate UIView (not self.view)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

Basically I want to screenshot a UIView which is called CustomViewLayout, which belongs to MyClass. MyClass's view is assigned to NormalView. Therefore if I call `self.view` it will reference NormalView. I have made a property `viewCustom` which is an outlet for CustomViewLayout. Anyways, I want to screenshot CustomViewLayout, I have tried this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.viewCustom.bounds.size, self.viewCustom.opaque, 0.0);

[self.viewCustom.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
```

That image is then displayed/attached inside an In-App Mail (`MFMailComposeViewController`). And it doesn't work, it shows a blue box with a question mark inside, which I presume means the image is not readable. I know there is nothing wrong with my In-App Mail image attachment code because if I change my screenshot code to screenshot `self.view` like below:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.viewCustom.bounds.size, self.viewCustom.opaque, 0.0);

[self.viewCustom.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
```

Then it works fine. So what should I do to screenshot my other view?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just easily to load the different nib name from MyClass and then reload it back later. 
Easy!